# Ipywidget button on_click call function with arguments

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

Running a jupyter notebook where i'm attempting to call a function on a button click. The function needs to take a value from a dropdown widget as an argument. Here's the code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import functools
from IPython.core.display import clear_output, display

def set_adc_precoder(_,adc_):
    with adc_precoder_out:
        clear_output()
        print("set_adc_precoder")
        print(adc_)
    
set_adc_precoder_btn = widgets.Button(description="Set ADC Precoder")
adc_precoder_select = widgets.Dropdown(options=range(0,16),description='ADC:')
adc_pre_form_items = [set_adc_precoder_btn, adc_precoder_select]
adc_pre_form = widgets.Box(adc_pre_form_items, layout=widgets.Layout(border='solid 2px',width='700px'))

adc_precoder_out = widgets.Output()

set_adc_precoder_btn.on_click(functools.partial(set_adc_precoder,\
                                                adc_ = adc_precoder_select.value))
                              
display(adc_pre_form,adc_precoder_out)
```

This gives the following output:
[image]

The value of the dropdown doesn't appear to be getting passed to the function. However, if I change:

```
set_adc_precoder_btn.on_click(functools.partial(set_adc_precoder,\
                                                adc_ = adc_precoder_select.value))
```

to:

```
set_adc_precoder_btn.on_click(functools.partial(set_adc_precoder,\
                                                adc_ = 7))
```

Then the value '7' gets passed as expected:

[image]

So it looks like the dropdown value isn't getting updated. Can anyone spot what i've missed here?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try importing `interact` from ipywidgets replacing `display(adc_pre_form,adc_precoder_out)` with `interact(adc_pre_form,adc_precoder_out)`? Cannot tell since you have only a bit of your code here. Best would be to make an smaller minimal reproducible example and share all. My suggestion assumes your last line in the cell will be `interact(adc_pre_form,adc_precoder_out)`. There's usually no need for display if you are calling widgets on last line.

Comment: Thanks. "interact" gave an error due to number of arguments. I read-up on "interact" and tried a few things but couldn't get it to work the way I wanted. I've got it working which i'll post as an answer shortly but it is not exactly how I would like to do it as it relies on global variables rather than passing a variable as an argument to a function.

Comment: You can try to use [`Mercury`](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) framework for converting notebooks into apps. The `Mercury` adds interactive widgets to the notebook based on the YAML header, so there is no need to code UI. The end-user can tweak widgets and execute notebook with new parameters.

Answer (score 0):

After some battling I went back to doing it the same way i've done before which uses global variables. I would rather pass the variable as an argument to the function ideally.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import functools
from IPython.core.display import clear_output, display

# ADC precoder form
def set_adc_precoder(_):
    with adc_precoder_out:
        clear_output()
        print("set_adc_precoder")
        print(adc_precoder_select.value)
        
set_adc_precoder_btn = widgets.Button(description="Set ADC Precoder")
adc_precoder_select = widgets.Dropdown(options=range(0,16),description='ADC:')
adc_pre_form_items = [set_adc_precoder_btn, adc_precoder_select]
adc_pre_form = widgets.Box(adc_pre_form_items, layout=widgets.Layout(border='solid 2px',width='700px'))
adc_precoder_out = widgets.Output()

set_adc_precoder_btn.on_click(set_adc_precoder)
                          
display(adc_pre_form,adc_precoder_out)
```